# Teardrops in Eagle

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication

Is there an *good and easy* way to add teardrops to traces in Eagle? See the red trace in the following image.

[image]

I have a board with a lot of vias and drawing the teardrops manually (as I have done in the image above) is not an option.

Comment: I am not familiar with Eagle myself but I believe it is quite common (in other software suites) to add teardrops either when generating the Gerbers or as a post-processing step applied to the Gerbers themselves.  Alternatively, most fab houses will be happy to add them automatically if you ask them, usually for free.

Comment: There are ULPs for that. Google Eagle teardrop ULP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eagle comes with an ULP called `teardrops.upl`, which does what you want:
[image]

You should do this as last step on a copy of your board, since this can not easily be undone.

Answer (score 3):

There is a July2015 version available in the ULP download resources that is MUCH faster (substantially rewritten) with added features. It is called teardrops_and_nfps200.ulp No reported bugs/problems. To find it, use the search keyword “teardrops”.

Comment: With the absorption of Eagle into Autodesk and the change in licensing, this ulp file has been removed from Eagle downloads. Is anyone aware of an alternative download location for those of us still using v7? I was unable to retrieve a copy from archive.org